# How to call POST API method which is hosted on IIS

Tags: .net, rest, api, iis, controller

I have a following http post and GET methods in MVC API Transaction controller;

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void ImportTransactions()
    {
      // import transactions

    }

 [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult IsApiAlive()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

API service is hosted on IIS, when i run the following URL in IE or Chrome to POST data then some how service is calling GET method not post method which is odd;

http://myserver01/Ftransactions/api/Transaction/ImportTransactions

URL works fine in postman when i select POST option from the dropdown.

Comment: If you access the URL directly in browser, it will get GET method. To post data, you need to call from different page using ajax or some other javascript library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending requests trough your bowsers URL bar or by clicking a link it will always be a GET request.
To have further request options like POST you need to use an HTML form or AJAX call (javascript) or have have a fancy little browser plugin installed.

E.g.:

```html
    <form action="/Ftransactions/api/Transaction/ImportTransactions" method="post">
          Data: 
          <input type="text" name="data">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Most browsers have something like a dev-tool which can often be started by pressing F12 on your keyboard or via the context menu (right click -> inspect). This allows to track the requests you're sending so you can see there of what type your requests are.

Please also mind the missing `I` in your methods name `mportTransactions()`